# Count emails in powershell

Tags: powershell, hashtable, exchange-server

I want to save undelivered emails addresses from Exchange 2010 and get result of table, which contains email and how many times it was undelivered. For that purpose I wrote script:

```
$all = Get-TransportServer | Get-MessageTrackingLog -EventID "FAIL" -start "04/14/2013" -resultsize unlimited | Select Recipients
$output = @{}
foreach($i in $all)
{ 
$v = $i.Recipients
if ($output.Contains($v))
{
$output.set_Item($v,$output[$v]+1)
$output[$v]
}
else
{
$output.Add($v, 1)
"new"
}
}
```

But it doesn't work. Please help to find out where is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use a collectinn ($recipents) as a hash table key in $output.

Get-messagetrackinglog can return a log of data.  I'd avoid Group-Object and stick with the hash table, but do it like this:

```
 $output = @{}

  Get-TransportServer |
  Get-MessageTrackingLog -EventID "FAIL" -start "04/14/2013" -resultsize unlimited |
  Select -Expand Recipients |
  foreach {$output[$_]++}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you avoid using `Group-Object` ?

Comment: It's a blocking (non-streaming) cmdlet. All of the pipeline input will accumulate there so it can be grouped.  If there's a lot of input it leads to high memory allocation to hold it.  With the hash table, the hash table key gets created/incremented, and then the input discarded at the end of the pipeline.

Comment: true, but there needs to be a lot of objects before that will be a problem since you're extracting just the recipients.

Comment: Granted. I may be over-cautious, but I collect about a quarter million log entries per day on my Exchange servers.  Beyond that, it may not really hurt anything to collect them, but there's also no reason I can think of to want to keep them.

Comment: That many huh? :S Yeah, I'm starting to see the picture. Thanks. That's the feedback I wanted since I don't have experience with Exchange or mail servers in general.

Answer (score 0):

I can't verify if you're using the mail-cmdlets correct, but to simplify you whole code, use `Select-Object -Expand` to split up all the arrays(if there are multiple reciepients for a mail) and `Group-Object` to count each address:

```
Get-TransportServer |
Get-MessageTrackingLog -EventID "FAIL" -start "04/14/2013" -resultsize unlimited |
Select-Object -ExpandProperty Recipients |
Group-Object |
Select Name, Count
```

To verify that the rest of the code works, you'll have to run

```
Get-TransportServer |
Get-MessageTrackingLog -EventID "FAIL" -start "04/14/2013" -resultsize unlimited
```

by itself to see it if returns the results you want.